# parsing JSON data with java script

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I use Google plus API and get this data from it and get an error while parsing this JSON data

[image: first part of json data that i parsing]

[image]

and here is the code I use to parse this data and get error as data object is tested and work fine and hold data as it appear in past 2 images

```
var allIems = data.items;
for (var element in allIems) {
  document.getElementById('datafromapi').innerHTML +=
    (" , published time :" + element.published +
      " , last updated time :" + element.updated +
      ", complete url : " + element.url

    );
  var obj = element.object.attachments;

  document.getElementById('datafromapi').innerHTML +=
    (+"\nattachments of post :\n" +
      " type : " +
      obj[0].objectType +
      " ,displayName of content : " +
      obj[0].displayName +
      " ,content URL  : " +
      obj[0].url +
      " ,content data :" +
      obj[0].image.url +
      " ,content type : " +
      obj[0].image.type +
      " ,content height : " +
      obj[0].image.height +
      " ,content width : " +
      obj[0].image.width +
      "\n\n\n");


}
});
```

i got that error appear

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attachments' of undefined

Comment: This error because NOT all `element` contain the `object` property.

Comment: the error is on **attachments** attribute not object and all elements have object attribute

Comment: @ahmedkhattab The error says that `element.object` is undefined. Since it's undefined, it doesn't have any attributes.

Comment: @ahmedkhattab he's right, the `object` attribute is undefined.

Comment: @ahmedkhattab Check your first item in your `allIems ` array.

Comment: thanks alot for all of you the solution of @Igor works fine with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element` values in

```
for (var element in allIems) {
```

are keys of `allItems`, which in this case are array indices. You have to address the actual array items like this:

```
var obj = allItems[element].object.attachments;
```

Your code `element.object.attachments;` tries to access property `object` of a number, which does not exist.

Since we know that `allItems` is an array, you could have written:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allIems.length; i++) {
  var obj = allItems[i].object.attachments;
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a built in JSON parser you can use that takes in a string of the data and returns an object.

```
let jsonDataAsString = "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}";

let jsonDataAsObject = JSON.parse(jsonDataAsString);
```

Then you can traverse through the data as an object, referencing properties using dot-notation

```
console.log(jsonDataAsObject.a); // 1
```

To be safe, you should be comparing properties to null before trying to use then

```
if(jsonDataAsObject.somePropery != null) {
    // the property exists so you can access it here
}
```

Comment: You likely want to check if the property is *undefined* first, as it could be defined and set to null (completely valid)

Comment: @scunliffe as far as I've ever used it null == undefined so as long as you us != you should be good. Though if you're someone who likes to use === then yes you would need to be more careful with checking before trying to access properties